# How to do atomic file replacement?

Tags: python, filesystems, rename, atomic, fwrite

What's the recommended way to replace a file atomically in Python?

i.e. if the Python script is interrupted, there is a power outage etc. files do not have a high probability of ending up in an inconsistent state (half written to the disk).

A solution for Linux/UNIX platforms is preferred.

(I know getting 100% atomic operations might depend on your file system, but at least make the chances for the corruption low.)

Comment: The answer would probably involve creating temporary files (on the same partition) and removing the existing target too

Comment: This is not a duplicate and has a much simpler answer than the question linked to, please reopen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a new file and os.rename() it over the existing file. This is atomic on [most platforms](http://www.weirdnet.nl/apple/rename.html) under [most conditions](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename).

Comment: `os.replace()` is atomic on ALL platforms under most conditions.