# Is it safe to rename a file to which PHP is continuously writing?

Tags: php, python, concurrency, filesystems

PHP continuously appends text to a file `foo.log` with mode `"a"`. I want to read the contents of `foo.log` in python and truncate the lines that have been read, while avoiding concurrent access issues between python and PHP.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645338/atomic-file-replacement-in-python) states that `os.rename` is atomic on most platforms. Thus, would it be safe to accomplish my goal by simplty renaming `foo.log` to `bar.log` and then read `bar.log` into python? Or do I need to implement a more complex solution, such as a shared lockfile?

Comment: You should probably use a database or a message broker.

Comment: @SynchroDynamic What do you mean by 'strategy object'? Also, renaming wouldn't create a duplicate file, it would simply erase the original. How would that lead to data corruption if the operation is atomic?

Comment: @Loïc I'm avoiding using a database as the data is ephemeral and would just lead to an unnecessarily high amount of INSERT and DELETE operations. A message broker sounds useful for a lot of continuous messages between php and python, but overly complex for this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not if you `fopen`.  What I use for logs is

```
file_put_contents( $filename, $data, FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
```

That way you don't have an open resource handle, and it will create a file if no exists when it goes to write.

I tried it once with `fwrite` with about 15 different processes all logging stuff, wound up with half a file of `NUL` crap in it.  So then I started using this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

> - **FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH**   Search for filename in the include directory. See include_path for more information.
> - **FILE_APPEND**     If file filename already exists, append the data to the file instead of overwriting it.
> - **LOCK_EX**     Acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing. In other words, a flock() call happens between the fopen() call and the fwrite() call. This is not identical to an fopen() call with mode "x".